# How to get props from another component in styled-components

Tags: styled-components

I'm trying to pass props to a child component's styled components so that I can dynamically set CSS styling. The below is what I tried, but it always goes false which is 50%. Seems like the props do not get passed down.

**components/Col.js**

```
const Col = styled.div`
  flex: ${props => (props.size < 6 ? "0 0 100%" : "0 0 50%")};
  max-width: ${props => (props.size < 6 ? "100%" : "50%")};
`;

export default ({ children }) => <Col>{children}</Col>;
```

**pages/index.js**

```
export default () => (
  <App>
    <Header />
    <Row>
      <Col size={3}>
        <Card />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </App>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your code in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epicpoincaresd6ig-sd6ig) and it functions as expected, there are 2 `<Col />`s, one which has a size of less than 6 and one greater, and the correct CSS rules are being applied based on props.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epicpoincaresd6ig-sd6ig

Are you sure it's not something in the `<Card />`'s CSS?  Maybe you can post a sandbox link demonstrating your issue.